# "window inside window" with Swing and Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm attempting to archive this effect:  http://www.ipadincanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/p_600_471_B35C968F-9122-464E-8859-1A1685FADF37.jpeg

I want to make an application which is all built into the same "window". There will be a menu bar, but when I click an option, instead of opening a new window I want a part of the first window to change to the new "view".

I'm using the Netbeans built in GUI designer, and I all I can seem to make are JFrames which result in different windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which lets you have JPanels that get switched out like cards. (Essentially, each "sub window" is a different JPanel that gets set as the visible one when it's selected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use follows

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)
- [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JPanel` for this purpose. Make one that holds other JPanels, and shift between them when you need to, like so:

```
children[0].setVisible(false); 
children[1].setVisible(true);
```

Or utilize `CardLayout` as it allows quick swapping and is essentially built for that purpose, hence the name.